# Retrieve data from collection/document inside of onCreate in firebase firestore with cloud function onCreate

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to retrieve the device token from my users collection in cloud firestore, inside of an onCreate. `d.get("token")`; below returns an undefined.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const fcm = admin.messaging();

exports.senddevices = functions.firestore
    .document("notification/{id}")
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const name = snap.get("name");
      const subject = snap.get("subject");

      return admin.firestore()
          .doc("users/{id}")
          .get()
          .then((d) => {
            if (!d.empty) {
              const payload = {
                notification: {
                  title: "from " + name,
                  body: "subject " + subject,
                  sound: "default",
                },
              };

              d.

              const token = d.get("token");

              return fcm.sendToDevice(token, payload);
            } else {
              console.log("User not found");
            }
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the value of ID from the path provided in `.document()` method and then use it in `.doc()` method to fetch the document as shown:

```
exports.senddevices = functions.firestore
    .document("notification/{id}")
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const name = snap.get("name");
      const subject = snap.get("subject");
      const id = context.params.id
      //    ^^ reading value of ID
      return admin.firestore()
          .doc("users/"+id) // <-- Using ID, 
          //or .doc(`users/${id}`)
          .get()
          .then((d) => {
            if (d.exists) {
              const payload = {
                notification: {
                  title: "from " + name,
                  body: "subject " + subject,
                  sound: "default",
                },
              };

              const token = d.data().token;

              return fcm.sendToDevice(token, payload);
            } else {
              console.log("User not found");
            }
          });
    });
```

Do notice you are fetching a single document so you should use `d.exists` to check if document exists instead of `.empty` which is used on a QuerySnapshot. Also to read value of token field you should first use `.data()` method to get contents of that document as an object.

Comment: Worked perfectly after changing !d.exists to d.exists. Thank you!!!

Comment: Great, I missed removing ! while changing empty to exists :)